# Writing to Excel fails - sometimes

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to write several HashMaps into an Excel. The first loop runs normal but doesn't show any cell values in the generated Excel.

Now the difficult part: The second loop, which uses the same methods, works perfectly fine!
**Both use the same method**: createCellValue(String)

Additonally, a comment I added to a cell is completely deplaced.

I have tried to restart my computer, delete the Excels and create completely new Excels.

The following is just the (in my eyes) relevant code. To see the full method and the console output, please check this gist: https://gist.github.com/meiswjn/e3e48f642279dc2eb0d2a16bd03cac6f

```
 public Workbook generateExcel() {
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Analysis");

    Row R0 = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    Row R1 = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
    Row R2 = sheet.createRow((short) 2);

    Function<Integer, Row> nextRow = (col) -> {
        if (!usedCoordinates.containsKey(col)) {
            System.out.println("Returned " + col + ":0");
            usedCoordinates.put(col, 0);
            return sheet.createRow(0);
        }
        int row = usedCoordinates.get(col);
        row++;
        usedCoordinates.put(col, row);
        System.out.println("Returned " + col + ":" + row);
        return sheet.createRow(row);
    };

              //--- Failing loop ---

    threadCfg.forEach((key, val) -> { //FAILS, sysos are printed
        System.out.println("Key: " + key);
        System.out.println("Value: " + val);
        Row row = nextRow.apply(8);
        row.createCell(8).setCellValue(key);
        row = null;
    });

    if (detailLevel != 99) {
        SXSSFDrawing drawing = (SXSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 10);
        Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);

        comment.setString(new XSSFRichTextString("As user requested compressed dataset (Detail Level: "
                + detailLevel
                + "), the latency values are averages of values ranging from Index-1 to Index. Export as 'Full' for complete dataset."));
        comment.setAuthor("InriVivit");

        R1.getCell(12).setCellComment(comment); //COMPLETELY DISPLACED
    }

    Map<Integer, Duration> latencyMap = insightGen.getIndexedLatencyMap(detailLevel);
    TreeMap<Integer, Duration> sortedLatencyMap = new TreeMap<>();
    sortedLatencyMap.putAll(latencyMap);
               //   --- WORKING LOOP ---

    sortedLatencyMap.forEach((key, val) -> { //WORKS
        Row row = nextRow.apply(11);
        row.createCell(11).setCellValue(key);
        row.createCell(12).setCellValue(val.toNanos() / 1000);
        row = null;
    });
    sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();

    for (int i = R1.getFirstCellNum(); R1.getLastCellNum() > i; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
    // workbook.createName().setNameName("InriVivit");
    return workbook;
}
```

Current Result:
[image: Current Result]

As you can see, the loop adding the latencys (col L&M) works perfectly fine and adds the data to the Excel. The loop adding the ThreadCfg-Values on the other hand doesn't result in any data displayed in the column (I).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Sheet.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow-int-) does exactly what it's method name tells. It **creates** a new empty row having the given row number in the sheet. So always when your `Function`' s `apply` method is called, new empty rows are created in the sheet. Cells which may be created in those rows before are deleted. So only the last created cells in those rows are present.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Richter. I will gladly mark your reply as the answer if you post it as such :)

Comment: No, it's a comment, not an answer. There are multiple more issues with your approach. For example: `SXSSF` is not thought to use as you are using it. `SXSSF` should completely fill rows because they then will be flushed to disk. It should not creating multiple rows partially filled and then getting those rows again and filling more data in them. Also I cannot see the advantage of your `Function` usage. And I cannot correct your code since not even your GitHubGist is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). So no answer possible here.